# Android SQLite Using two spinners as view filters

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview, filtering, android-spinner

MAIN QUESTION:

Wondering if there's any conflict with the two spinners when I try display the results with my LoadGrid. Like if one is overriding the other and ending up with an empty result because of it. If so how do I go about combining the two results from the spinners to get the desired view.

SOME DETAILS:

I want to use two spinners on my gridview to act as filters. One for TERMS and one for STATUS. Specifically what I want to happen is that the user can use those two spinners INDIVIDUALLY or TOGETHER to filter the view of accounts in the DB.

Taking it one step at a time I've gotten one spinner running and working properly. So I cloned that working spinner code to get my second one up and running. Nope, not working. Using either of the two spinners now result in nothing. No accounts show up anymore. It'll let me select from the spinners but my grid will still be empty.

If anything is missing or you need to see more of the code please feel free to ask. Cheers.

Here's the spinners snippets:

```
        Utilities.ManageTermSpinner(this.getParent(), spinTerm);
    try {

        spinTerm.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int arg2, long arg3) {
                LoadGrid();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        txtTest.setText(ex.toString());
    }


    Utilities.ManageStatSpinner(this.getParent(), spinStat);
    try {

        spinStat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                      int arg2, long arg3) {
                LoadGrid();


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
       });

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        txtTest2.setText(ex.toString());
    }

}
```

Here's the LoadGrid that it references:

```
    public void LoadGrid() {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {

        View v = spinTerm.getSelectedView();
        TextView txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTermClass);
        String Terms = String.valueOf(txt.getText());
        Cursor c = dbHelper.getAccByTerms(Terms);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        View x = spinStat.getSelectedView();
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) x.findViewById(R.id.txtStatID);
        String Status = String.valueOf(txt2.getText());
        Cursor b = dbHelper.getAccByStatus(Status);
        startManagingCursor(b);

        String[] from = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.colName, DatabaseHelper.colAmount, DatabaseHelper.colTermsClass, DatabaseHelper.colStatClass};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.colName, R.id.colAmount, R.id.colTerms, R.id.colStat};

        SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.gridrow, c, from, to);
        grid.setAdapter(sca);

        SimpleCursorAdapter sba = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.gridrow, b, from, to);
        grid.setAdapter(sba);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        b.setMessage(ex.toString());
        b.show();
    }
}
```

The dbHelper snippets for TERMS and STATUS:

```
public Cursor getAccByTerms(String Terms)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String [] columns=new String[]{"_id",colName,colAmount,colPurpose,colTermsClass,colDate,colEditDate,colStatClass};
    Cursor c=db.query(viewAccs, columns, colTermsClass+"=?", new String[]{Terms}, null, null, null);
    return c;
}

public Cursor getAccByStatus(String Status)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String [] columns=new String[]{"_id",colName,colAmount,colPurpose, colTermsClass,colDate,colEditDate,colStatClass};
    Cursor d=db.query(viewAccs,columns, colStatClass +"=?",new String[]{Status},null,null,null);
    return d;
}
```

And the Utilities snippet where I keep the ManageSpinner stuff:

```
public class Utilities {
static public void ManageTermSpinner(Context context, Spinner view) {
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    Cursor c = dbHelper.getAllTerms();

    SimpleCursorAdapter ca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.termspinnerrow, c, new String[]{DatabaseHelper.colTermsClass, "_id"}, new int[]{R.id.txtTermClass});

    view.setAdapter(ca);


}

static public void ManageStatSpinner(Context context, Spinner view) {
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    Cursor d = dbHelper.getAllStatus();

    SimpleCursorAdapter da = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context,R.layout.statspinnerrow, d, new String[]{DatabaseHelper.colStatClass,"_id"}, new int[]{R.id.txtStatClass});

    view.setAdapter(da);
}
```

Comment: I don't really get the question but I understand you want to filter the results based on two conditions. You will have to change the sqlite query you are using. Use the AND clause with where clause to filter the results based on two spinners. better write this code "dbHelper.getAccByTerms(Terms);"

Comment: Thanks for the reminders. Clarified my main concern and added the snippets. I'll look into the AND and WHERE clauses you mentioned and get back to you. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you need to do it:

```
public Cursor getAccByTermsAndStatus(String Terms, String status)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String [] columns=new String[]{"_id",colName,colAmount,colPurpose,colTermsClass,colDate,colEditDate,colStatClass};
    Cursor c=db.query(viewAccs, columns, colTermsClass+"=? AND " + colStatClass + "=?", new String[]{Terms, status}, null, null, null);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Yeah got pretty much the same code when I tried to use the WHERE and OR clauses you mentioned except my syntax is all wrong with the " " haha. Thank you very much, cheers!